# How can I fix N+1 problem in Hibernate & Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate

I am trying to extract a list of all users from a database (Postgres), using Hibernate & Spring Data JPA. But when the logs from Hibernate are enabled, I see that I get not one select, as I expect, but several:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_ from user user0_
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
```

Here is all the code related to database entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)                   
    private Set<Role> roles;
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
 }
```

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findAllBy();
}
```

Tell me, please, how can I get rid of the extra selects so that only 1 remains in the end?

Comment: I doubt that that is all the code. Also your `findAllBy` is doing the same as the original `findAll` which I suggest to use. The `roles` are lazy loaded so unless you aren't using that it wouldn't be loaded, so you are probably mapping it or displaying it and it needs to be loaded. If you want to load it eagerly then either make the collection eagerly loaded or write a specific query that loads it eagerly for this usecase

Answer (score 2):

There is `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` in the `@ManyToMany` association

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)                   
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Hibernate shouldn't load roles. And additional selects shouldn't appear.

Possible reasons:

1. Roles loaded afterwards by lazy loading. You can add log entry just after the first select. Also you can remove `@Transactional` annotation to have `LazyInitializationException`.
2. You use a debugger. Roles can be loaded by debugger, because it uses, for example, `toString()` from `User`.
3. Any method of `User`, not only `getRoles().something()`, can case lazy loading. For example `toString()`.

You can try to debug and see when the first role select appears.